# Not able to set height and width on a canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I am creating a canvas object with javascript and trying to set height and width on it, but it isn't creating a canvas with the required dimensions. Please tell me where I am going wrong.
Here's the code -

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const a = document.createElement('a');
canvas.style.height = '1000px';
canvas.style.width = '1000px';
a.href = canvas.toDataUrl('image/jpg');
a.download = 'download.jpg';
a.click();
```

The downloaded image seems to be of much smaller dimensions and not of what is specified(1000px * 1000px)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set the width/height of a HTMLCanvasElement, you need to set them directly on the canvas element, not on its style. So it should look like this:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const a = document.createElement('a');
canvas.height = '1000px';
canvas.width = '1000px';
a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
a.download = 'download.jpg';
a.click();
```

Also, you misspelled the function `.toDataURL()`, URL is capitalized there.

Comment: Read more about HTMLCanvasElement here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: The values of the `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas should not contain 'px', i.e. they should be like `canvas.height = '1000'`

Answer (score 0):

Try with attributes, not the style: `canvas.height` instead of `canvas.style.height`.  One is the presented resolution, the other is the actual pixel height.  It's confusing, but let's you control upscaling.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Should give you a canvas with a 1000x1000 resolution.